# jquery drag and drop - dragging between two list, how to delete selected list in drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Pls drag more than 2 from "Listed Responsibilities" in to "Selected items"

If i delete any of the list(li) in "Selected items", the deleted list need be to add in "Listed Responsibilities" is this possible

My working example:
jsfiddle.net/n8AEw/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8AEw/7/) for you. You can use [$.append](http://api.jquery.com/next/) too add a html tags into an element, like below:

```
$("#sortable-right").on("click", ".drop-close", function(){
        $("ul#sortable-left").append('<li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle"> <strong>'+$(this).parents("li").find("strong").text()+'</strong><div class="ui-plus-desc"> <a href="#" class="drop-close">                                                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a><span>at 11:47, 21 June 2014 </span><span>by Mark Antany</span></div></li>');
    });
```

Hope it helps..

Note: Inside the `append` is html tags that are copied from `<li>` inside `ul#sortable-left`, I just change the `<strong>` text.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. i really happy with your quick response.

Keep rocks guys

Comment: Your welcome, I happened to see your question too.. +1 wont hurt.. ^^